# FirebaseCrashlytics, will not report Exceptions but running .crash will

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

Below is a code that i have to initialize an run my app with.
As a test i have a future that will throw an exception (out of range), this is how ever not sent to crashlystics?

If i issue a FirebaseCrashlystics.instance.crash() it will send a report.
I have changed the filter to Event-type="non-fatals" but i can not see my errors there.

I don't know what i am missing?

```
class AppConfig {
  final String appTitle;
  final BuildFlavor buildFlavor;
  final bool initializeCrashlytics, enableCrashlyticsInDevmode;

  AppConfig(
      {@required this.appTitle,
      @required this.buildFlavor,
      this.initializeCrashlytics = true,
      this.enableCrashlyticsInDevmode = true});

  Future<void> _testAsyncErrorOnInit() async {
    Future<void>.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () {
        final List<int> list = <int>[];
        print(list[100]);
      },
    );
  }

  Future startCrashlytics() async {
    Function originalError = FlutterError.onError;
    if (this.initializeCrashlytics) {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
          .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(this.enableCrashlyticsInDevmode);
      FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) async {
        await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError(errorDetails);
        originalError(errorDetails);
      };
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash(); << This works

      // await _testAsyncErrorOnInit(); << This doesn't Yes i do comment crash and uncomment this.
    }
  }

  Future run() async {
    // Lägg in initiering av firebase, crashlytics
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    await startCrashlytics();

    runApp(ElectronicCupongs(appTitle: appTitle));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you checked the [package's example](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics/example), but is your app wrapped in `runZonedGuarded`?

The example page contains the required details, but you can also check the package's files or, a more readable format, [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/usage/).

Comment: Hi!

This does work for the outer code, but then in other code segments, i tried this to but didn't work either.

Should i manually log on exceptions in the Try Catch block?

I tought this was handled on general error but perhaps Exceptions are not ment to be catched and reported to crashlystics?

I have noticed that crashes and non severe crashes like when i get a red screen with an error is displayed, this is logged.

I hope you do understand :)

Comment: @Martin, sorry that I didn't respond earlier, but someone else managed this segment. From my understanding, you need to catch the errors for crashlytics. Here's snippet from a `catch (error, stackTrace)`: `await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stackTrace, reason: reasonForCrash);`. I'll try to come back with more info once I wrap it up!